# Is there a word for two words that refer to something similar but aren't identical?

Tags: hypernyms, terminology

The best example I came up with is the following:

Just for the sake of argument, *Eastern Orthodox* and *Catholic*; two words which refer to similar religions, but are not identical.

How would that be defined?

Comment: I don't know if there's a dedicated technical term for this, other than your simple, straightforward, *similar*. You could, of course, construct phrases to express your meaning "*they're in the same family*" and so on.

Comment: They are *related* terms.

Comment: @DanBron: I misunderstood. Didn't realize the OP was asking for a term that relates the two words.

Comment: @TusharRaj no worries, I've been scratching my head for several hours now. Can't seem to find anything about it, and that's I pledged my case to the masters here.

Comment: I think it's a poor example, because if the "two religions" are so similar, how come they are still split today, almost 1000 after the Great Schism? Second, as words *orthodox* (correct belief/glory) and *catholic* (according to the whole) do not have, technically speaking, similar meanings.

Comment: @pazzo I corrected the capitalization and added links to the specific words OP intended (so it doesn't change pendants like you and me ;). And Catholic and Orthodox are very similar compared to, say, Protestant or even Islam.

Comment: Aren't such words called *synonyms*? Am I missing some nuance in the question?

Comment: The words *orthodox* and *catholic* have very different meanings.

Comment: Correlative ? A word or concept that has a mutual relationship with another word or concept.

Comment: @TimRomano They're not synonyms. There is no sentence in which you could substitute one with the other without a significant change in meaning.

Comment: @DanBron: I'm not talking about the specific examples OP has given, but about the question in the title.

Comment: @TimRomano Yes. The capitalization has been corrected to satisfy our more pedantic itches.

Comment: @DanBron: I don't know what you're talking about. I changed "definition" to "word" in my edit.

Comment: I think Correlative suits the case. It's the most accurate definition to this case I saw so far

Comment: @TimRomano I'm not sure which of my comments your most recent comment refers to, but my "capitalization" comment referred back to your "orthodox and catholic have different meanings" comment (which I took to echo pazzo's original sentiment: the words, uncapitalized, are generic adjectives, but capitalized, denote [broadly similar] sects of the Christian church).

Comment: @w0rldart Catholic is *correlative of* Eastern Orthodox? Doesn't ring right to me.

Comment: @DanBron Well, let me put it this way. Both religions, have priests, monks and other related organisational levels, but yet they differ in things like: when they celebrate Easter, their saints, parts of the sermon and so on. So there is a level of similarity, when you think about those two, but they are not identical

Comment: @Dan Bron, et al. The "best example" that the OP "can come up with" is still a poor one. I think the OP should be highly encouraged to come up with a different one, or if they are actually asking about the "two religions," they should make this clear.

Comment: @w0rldart No, no, I agree with the basic premise of the question and the specific example used (I've been defending it here against its detractors)! I simply don't like *correlative* as a solution.

Comment: @DanBron oh, I see what you mean. But, definition to correlative on google is "having a mutual relationship; corresponding." I don't know what else could fit better

Comment: @w0rldart It's too broad. You might as well use *similar* or *related*. You might wish to look up how *correlative* is actually used in context. Try looking it up in the COCA corpus and see what its collocations are. Using it this way is awkward, unidiomatic, and overbroad.

Comment: This question is now off topic, as it is chiefly about religion (in fact two of them) and not chiefly about English.

Comment: @DanBron There are no exact synonyms (except maybe in math). A synonym doesn't have to be replaceable absolutely everywhere with no change in meaning.

Comment: @w0rldart: Please edit your example to remove the religious tones from it. I think it is confusing people about what you're asking. You could use lions and tigers being animals or something.

Comment: @w0rldart This is confusing. Do you care about the names of the religions or the non-religious adjectives 'catholic' and 'orthodox'?

Comment: @Mitch Synonyms must be replaceable in *some* context. I cannot, off he top of my head, think of a context where one could substitute *Roman Catholic* for *Eastern Orthodox*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Co-hyponyms** seems to be it.

See this image from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy):

[image]

Comment: @TusharRaj Well, that's a cute solution! Given your tree diagram, How about *sibling words* or *sister terms*, or something like that, as well?

Comment: @DanBron: The word that came to my mind was 'Bronyms'

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP has accepted the editing of his question to be asking specifically about "two religions" (which seems to be ratified by the OP's editing of Orthodox (capital O) to Eastern Orthodox...

I reject the premise of the question, which I take to be that the "two religions" are **similar**.

I am also unaware that the two religions are "similar but not identical."

In fact, since this is now a religious and/or historical question, it is both *off topic* and it is a matter of perspective.

For instance, the teaching of Roman Catholicism and Protestantism on certain issues are much more similar to each other (both being Western, and heavily dependent upon [Augustine of Hippo](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustine_of_Hippo)) than either is to Eastern Orthodox teaching on the same issues.

My answer is **ecclesiastical bodies who are not in earthly communion**.

Comment: This is a comment, perhaps one that belongs on a close vote. But it is not an answer.

Comment: +1 for rejecting the premise. It's like saying Sunni and Shia are "similar but not identical". Such abstractions don't get one very far.  They are "historically related". They "have a history".  Almost anything is better than "not identical" which is borderline meaningless in this context.

Comment: It is now an answer.

Answer (score -1):

*orthodox" and *catholic* are adjectives.  That which is *orthodox* is that which has been deemed not to violate a system of unified belief. *Un*orthodox ideas get **eliminated**. The idea behind *catholic* is nearly the opposite; it means "**including** variety" or "encompassing". By virtue of their meanings, and by virtue of the dynamics of belief systems, these adjectives get applied to organizations and movements involving ideas, beliefs, tenets, etc.

I know of no abstract label for words that get applied to the same domain or a dynamic, because their meanings are apt.

Comment: Stop it. The capitalization of the two words *Orthodox* and *Catholic* was corrected -- with links to the two specific words actually being compared -- in an edit long before you posted this answer. Answer the question as asked, please.

Comment: @DanBron: We are not on the same wavelength here.  The capitalization is not relevant. The proper names are formed from the underlying adjectives.

Comment: But the proper names *mean something different now*, and are literally different words (distinguished by their capitalization). The Pope may or may not be *catholic*, but the Pope sure as heck is *Catholic*. It is the proper names which are being asked about and compared here, nor the underlying adjectives.

Comment: @DanBron: I disagree. The proper names refer to the organizations/religions but the meaning of the adjectives has not been lost.   Are Elk and Rotarian "correlatives" at some lexical level?

Comment: Of course I agree the meanings of the adjectives haven't been lost. But that's not what's being asked about! Your answer is not addressing the question, it's making up its own question and responding to *that*. To be clear, the question is **not** "What is the relationship between the words *orthodox* and *catholic*?", the question **is** "What is the relationship between the words *Orthodox* and *Carholic*?".

Comment: @DanBron: The question sucks *qua* question. Please quote it to me. Where is it?

Comment: Its right above your question. Up there ^. I've also recapitulated it in my previous comment (though my dumb thumb hit "send" too soon).

Comment: @DanBron: You're being coy.  The question in the title does not really match the example in the body of the post, and the body of the post does not contain a clear question. To what does "that" refer in the final sentence?  My answer addresses the putative "similarity" referred to in the title.

Comment: @TimRomano I am not being coy. The title is a broad heading, as titles tend to be and sometimes necessarily are. The question is clear as day, and you're willfully misunderstanding it because you don't like the example given paragraph (I imagine; though I really don't know why the question bugs you so much). The *that* is an ellipsis: *things like that*, where the antecedent of that *that* and the referent of *things like* is the example given in the preceding q.v. Orthodox (capitalized and linked) and Catholic (capitalized and linked).

Comment: @DanBron: if the question is as clear as day, please paraphrase it for me rather than calling me willfully obtuse.  I will admit to obtuseness when enlightened. But not to willful obtuseness.

Comment: @TimRomano First, I explicitly and intentionally did *not* call you *obtuse*: *obtuse* is a characteristic; *misunderstanding* is a behavior. Do not put words in my mouth. Second, a paraphrase: "The terms *Catholic* and *[Eastern] Orthodox* refer to closely related, but not identical, ideas. They conjure up similar images and evoke similar feelings. They're not far apart by neither can they be used as substitutes for one another. What is the technical linguistic term for the relationship of two similar-but-distinct terms like *Orthodox* and *Catholic*?".

Comment: @Dan Bron In who(m) do these terms "conjure up similar images and evoke similar feelings"? How can one call either church/religion an "idea"? On what basis do you say the two are "not far apart"?

Comment: Roman Catholic and Eastern Orthodox religious adherents are on far friendlier terms than Shia and Sunni today, and on far friendlier terms than some Protestant and Roman Catholic adherents were with the Reformation. But history is off-topic here (except insofar as it relates to language).   I cannot find the clear linguistic question here.

Comment: @pazzo In who(m)? Clearly OP, for one. Me, for another. On what basis? Here's [one OP offered](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249700/is-there-a-word-for-two-words-that-refer-to-something-similar-but-not-identical#comment542770_249700). I [offered another](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249700/is-there-a-word-for-two-words-that-refer-to-something-similar-but-not-identical#comment542755_249700) in my original comment directed at you. It's all relative. In re: ideas, ideas are the referents of words.

Comment: @Dan Bron I agree it's all relative, which is why I find the 'best example' the OP could think of to be a very poor one. These two "words" they mention are living traditions. Given the old adage about religion and politics, I think the OP would do better to think harder.